# How to get the output from dbtop command on mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is actually there a way to get the output from dbtop to see how many writes, reads and updates are being performed in real time by the database/replicaSet?

I'am trying to figure this out using Python. With the pymongo lib.

I can get a couple of statistics from the database using some commands like:

```
client = MongoCliente(server, port)
client.admin.command('serverStatus')
```

Any tip to how to do that to dbtop?

```
client.admin.command('dbtop')?
```

Comment: What do you mean by dbtop? Do you mean mongotop?

Comment: When i enter in the mongoD instance on port 27018 i can see a "dbtop (occurrences|percent of elapsed)" with a table as real statistics data from what currently operations are running. I want to know if the same command is avaible for python and how to execute it.

Comment: Can you run mongotop command from command line or mongostats and see if there similar results to whatever you see in dbtop?

Comment: I can't. I'am trying to figure out how to get this infos through python.

Comment: And I was trying to help you. But if it is too hard for you to run the command and to see results, most probably it is too hard for me to try.

Answer (score 0):

The command is `top` as per https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/top/

So you can do:
`client.admin.command('top')`